# Code completion not working in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to get code completion for the psycopg2 library in PyCharm 2018.1 but it is not showing cursor class methods like .execute() or .fetchone().

Here is my code:

```
import logging
import psycopg2 as pg

#Code completion works fine here.
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.info("Hello World!")

#Code completion works fine here.
con = pg.connect("dbname='postgres' port='5432'")

#Code completion not working!
cur = con.cursor()
```

Comment: What does not working mean? What happens when you are editing code? Have you contacted Jet Brains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because:

> Psycopg 2 is mostly implemented in C as a libpq wrapper

So you have autocomletion for `pg.connect()` because it exists in [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/master/lib/__init__.py#L81) and mostly the rest of features are listed as *.c* and *.h* files https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/tree/master/psycopg that are being handled by [`setup.py`](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/master/setup.py#L624-L628).

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution is to reset the settings.
From the main menu, select File > Manage IDE Settings > Restore Default Settings.

Alternatively, press `Shift` twice and type `Restore default settings`